# .htaccess rewrite loads files from wrong directory

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using `RewriteRule`to create SEO friendly urls. After creating rule its looking for external files in wrong directories.

.htaccess file code:

```
# 1 -- Error 404 --
ErrorDocument 404 /NotFound.php

#2 -- IGNORE INDEX --
IndexIgnore *
#3 -- Default charter set --
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

RewriteEngine On       
RewriteRule ^questions/([0-9]+) questions.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Normally it loads CSS from `css/filename.css`.
After applying rewrite rule it load files from `questions/filename.css`

How can I create a `RewriteRule` which just changes URL behavior and how to force `questions.php?id=34&title=something` to `questions/34/something` automatically?

Comment: Use the `<base>` element in `questions.php`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For css problem just use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.

**Otherwise** You can add this just below `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />` so that every **relative URL** is resolved from that base URL and not from the current page's URL.

For 2nd problem you need redirect rules to redirect old URLs to pretty links.

Have it this way:

```
# 1 -- Error 404 --
ErrorDocument 404 /NotFound.php

#2 -- IGNORE INDEX --
IndexIgnore *
#3 -- Default charter set --
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On   

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /questions\.php\?id=([^\s&]+)&title=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /questions/%1/%2? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /questions\.php\?id=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /questions/%1? [R=302,L,NE]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^questions/([0-9]+)/?$ questions.php?id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^questions/([0-9]+)/([\w-]+)/? questions.php?id=$1&title=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```